# MySql Get records only from child table where the parent key has multiple values

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables parent and child. Parent has a field called unique_id and child has a field called parent_unique_id and it is the foreign key in the child table. Parent table has 4 records for the same unique_id and child table has 5 records for the same unique_id.

When I join them to get the records, I am getting a total of 20 records each 5 records of the child table are repeating 4 times.

The query I am using is

```
SELECT c.* FROM child c JOIN parent p ON c.parent_unique_id = p.unique_id
```

I tried LEFT JOIN as well but I am still getting 20 records which are repeated.

Comment: What isn't `unique_id` unique in `Parent`?  That seems like a very misleading naming convention.

Comment: That was a technical mistake happened while I started to build it. Now I am working on to separate that unique_id into a different table. Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM child c 
WHERE c.parent_unique_id IN (SELECT p.unique_id FROM parent p);
```

Of course, you could just slap `SELECT DISTINCT` on your query.  However, that requires and unnecessary processing.

Comment: It worked. Thank You. I will mark the answer but let me wait for some more answers.